# does testcafe support the pasting of images?

Tags: javascript, devexpress, clipboard, paste, testcafe

*The [Testcafe forum](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/) and [Github repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=question.md) both ask that all questions about Testcafe should now be posted to StackOverflow.*

I have a bit of functionality that I'd like to test which involves pasting an image from the clipboard. You can test it out quickly by doing a print screen and pasting into a Github comment field. Even StackOverflow has some paste functionality in the question editor.

So can I paste an image using Testcafe? The only issue related to this I found was https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2668 which was asking about the simulating the ClipboardApi from 2018. This isn't that exactly.

```
test('test paste', async t => {
  var image = "base64encodedImage?";
  await t
    .copyToClipboard(image)
    .focus('textarea')
    .pressKey('ctrl+v');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot paste using TestCafe so pasting an image is out of the question.

This feature has been requested but is not yet implemented:
https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2466

I tried work several variations to paste.

```
await t.typeText(rte.text, '', { paste: true });
await t.typeText(rte.text, 'v', { modifiers: { ctrl: true } });
await t.pressKey('ctrl+v');
```